# Change div blocks onclick

Tags: javascript, onclick, show-hide

Have a nice day, dear Programmers!
On G + is a block Posts; About; Photos; Videos
https://plus.google.com/109813896768294978296/posts
when you click for example on the About, there is a change at the bottom of div that contains a specific content. As I understand it, realize it is not difficult, but I'm afraid to write ten lines of code is very dirty because, in addition to jquery, because I am only a beginner. Can someone push on the right track, or to show where it has already been implemented in the demo with source code? Thanks!

```
<div id="109813896768294978296-posts-page" class="c-ha-If" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="false">…</div>
```

```
<div id="109813896768294978296-about-page" class="c-ha-If c-ha-jb" role="tabpanel" aria-hidden="true">…</div>
```

Comment: [link](http://onlinetools.org/tools/domtabdata/) [link](http://livepipe.net/control/tabs) **with AJAX - ** [link](http://www.crackajax.net/tabs.php) [link](http://www.developersnippets.com/?p=22) [link](http://www.noupe.com/javascript/37-great-ajax-css-tab-based-interfaces.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are two things occurring when you click on About from Posts. It appears to be adding and removing CSS classes dynamically. Which you can do with http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/.

As for loading data into a div from a URL, use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/.
Once you've got the data, you can use http://api.jquery.com/html/.

If you've already loaded everything and want to achieve tab switching: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: **Aram Kocharyan** Excellent! Thank you very much for your reply I am very grateful!
Preferably without jQuery but it's probably in the future when I'll teach myself javascript

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention that you would indeed need javascript. However, I have seen CSS3 do nifty things, but the majority of people would implement it in js. Start here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/ I was also putting it off for a long time, but I sat down to it and picked it up by the end of the day. If you've programmed anything before it's a cinch. And if you haven't, it's an easy language to make your first.